# How can I customize my UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to know how can I customize my UITableViewCell like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the official docs: [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7) at the point "Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files"

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to know how to customize the UITableView, which you do by drawing your own UITableViewCell.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500980/how-to-add-star-rating-to-uitableview-cell) - "To add a star just use a UIButton with the default image of a unhighlighted star and a selected image of a highlighted star."

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post, it helped me a lot when I first deal with this problem:
[Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)